# Replacing the letters of a String with blank if they are found in another

Tags: java, string

I am working on an assignment and this part is tripping me up.

**Construct cipher1** by first filling in the matrix with the unique letters from the first key.

For example, if the key is `“testkey”`, then fill in the key with the letters **T, E, S, K, Y**.

Do not fill in repeated characters from the key. Then fill the matrix with the remaining characters of the alphabet (again, skipping Q).

Do not repeat any characters that appeared in the key. So, for **“testkey”,** **cipher1** looks like this: "

The cypher is a **5 by 5** array usually filled with the letters of the alphabet minus 'q'.

So if my key is testkey, the cipher will now be filled with `"TESKYABCDFGHIJLMNOPRUVWXZ" instead of "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ".`

I thought something like this would work but it doesn't.

```
for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        key.toCharArray();
        alphabet.replace(key[i], "");
    }
```

The key variable being a string **"TESTKEY"** and the alphabet variable also being a string containing "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ".

Looking at it now that code is obviously flawed and now I'm just stuck. Please any one give the suggestion to me

Comment: Strings in java are immutable. Reassign to alphabet variable the new string that is returned as a result of calling replace.

Comment: I suggest you research and read up on what does it mean that Java Strings are immutable, then after you understand that, try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String testS = "testkey";
    String key = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";

    testS = testS.toUpperCase() + key;
    testS = removeDuplicates(testS);
    System.out.println(testS);
}

static String removeDuplicates(String string) {

    StringBuilder noDuplicateChars = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        String letter = string.substring(i, i + 1);

        if (noDuplicateChars.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
            noDuplicateChars.append(letter);
        }
    }

    return noDuplicateChars.toString();
}
```

If from some reason you don't want to use `StringBuilder`, you can change the implementation of `removeDuplicates` to :

```
static String removeDuplicates(String string) {

    String noDuplicates = new String("");

    for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {

        if (!noDuplicates.contains("" + string.charAt(i))) {
            noDuplicates += "" + string.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return noDuplicates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). In for loop add `key` characters and in second loop add `alphabet` characters. Then iterate through set elements and build string.

Note that method `add` do not place element if it already exist in the set, hence no additional checks are needed.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to use regular expression;

example: 1 - key

```
input: testkey
code: `String newString = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1").toUpperCase();` 
output: TESKY
```

Example 2; Concat newString with the alphapatical string

```
input: testkey + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ";
code: `String FinalString = input.replaceAll("(.)\\1{1,}", "$1").toUpperCase();`
output: TESKYABCDFGHIJLMNOPRUVWXZ
```

Comment: I doubt that was the teacher's intent, for him to use regex. P.S. your replaceall doesn't work.